# How to remove Apache webserver in Centos 6

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, centos6

I use Centos 6 64 Bit. I have installed Reverse-proxy NGINX + Apache through Directadmin. But I want to completely remove Apache service and use NGINX. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply issue the command `yum remove httpd`

Comment: I want all the processes controlled by NGINX. When i remove the Apache, which settings do i need to use next?